# Manage Windows Aero shake feature with custom title bar

Tags: java, javafx, titlebar

There are many tutorials or questions related to custom title bar with JavaFX

I created a custom title bar like this:

[image: custom bar]

I can move the windows but now (because the windows is `UNDECORATED` I can't apply any native Windows feature like the `Aero shake` (if you shake a window, all other app are reduced)

Is there any solution to manage this type of feature with a custom title bar?

Here is my code:

start.java:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
    prStage = primaryStage;
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../gui/main.fxml"));
    prStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

    //prStage.setOpacity(0.75);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 360);
    prStage.setScene(scene);
    prStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/resource/Images/icon.png"));
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("..//gui/css/NewUICSS.css").toExternalForm());
    prStage.show();
}
```

main controller:

```
public class NewUIController {
    private static double xOffset = 0;
    private static double yOffset = 0;

    public void initialize() {
        moveBar.setOnMousePressed(this::mousePressed);
        moveBar.setOnMouseDragged(this::mouseDrag);
        moveBar.setOnMouseReleased(this::mouseRealease);

        mnuBar.setOnMousePressed(this::mousePressed);
        mnuBar.setOnMouseDragged(this::mouseDrag);
        mnuBar.setOnMouseReleased(this::mouseRealease);
    }

    private void mouseDrag(MouseEvent event){
        MainJavaFx.getPrimaryStage().setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
        MainJavaFx.getPrimaryStage().setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
    }

    private void mouseRealease(MouseEvent event){
        if(event.getSceneY() == 0){
            MainJavaFx.getPrimaryStage().setY(0);
        }else if(MainJavaFx.getPrimaryStage().getY() < 0){
            MainJavaFx.getPrimaryStage().setY(0);
        }
    }

    private void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
        xOffset = event.getSceneX();
        yOffset = event.getSceneY();
    }

    public void close(){
        ((Stage)pnPrincipal.getScene().getWindow()).close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these problems exist only on windows, so we need to use an other "style" than the undecorated style to manage all windows features.

You need to use two libraries:

- jna : point on you windows
- jna-platform : create an appropriate style

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
    prStage = primaryStage;
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../gui/NewUI2.fxml"));

    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1280, 720));
    Main.getPrimaryStage().getScene().getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("..//gui/css/main-black.css").toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.show();

    // verify if it is windows
    if(System.getProperty("os.name").indexOf("win") >= 0)
        long lhwnd = com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getWindows().get(0).getNativeWindow();
        Pointer lpVoid = new Pointer(lhwnd);
        WinDef.HWND hwnd = new WinDef.HWND(lpVoid);
        final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
        int oldStyle = user32.GetWindowLong(hwnd, WinUser.GWL_STYLE);
        int newStyle = oldStyle | 0x00020000;//WS_MINIMIZEBOX
        user32.SetWindowLong(hwnd, WinUser.GWL_STYLE, newStyle);
    }
}
```

But I don't know if it is the best way to do that.